# Get object in array that contains closest matching id property in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

I am wondering if there is a better way to do get the result.
I have an array of objects, each object contains an id as a string path pattern. I want to return the object that has the best match to a url path. ATM I am using lodash

All id's are unique.

```js
const url = '/economia/finanzas/moodys-coloca-calificaciones-de-riesgo-de-costa/JZF24QAQHBBFPLJQL5VZJPKCZA/story/'
const sites = [{
  '_id': '/la-nacion/economia'
}, {
  '_id': '/la-nacion'
}, {
  '_id': '/la-nacion/economia/finanzas'
}, {
  '_id': '/la-nacion/economia/moodys'
}]

const urlArr = url.split('/')

const compare = sites.map(site => {
  // get all matches
  const siteArr = site._id.split('/')
  // get lengths of matches
  return _.intersection(siteArr, urlArr).length
})
// get index of obj with best match
const indexOfBestMatch = _.indexOf(compare, _.max(compare))
// new primary section
const newPrimarySection = sites.filter((e, i) => {
  return i === indexOfBestMatch
})

console.log(newPrimarySection)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsbin.com/lumepereyi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: If your code is working properly but you'd just like to know if there is a better way to go about it, then this question belongs on [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise, you'll need to explain what it is about your current method that isn't working.

Comment: I feels clunky. I am just wondering if there is a more creative way to getting the best matched _id.
In the code:
- converting the string url to an array
- mapping though every object id and converting it to an array
- using intersection to get only the matched items in the return with length
- finding the highest number in the array and returning the index
- going back to array object to filter for the object in the matching index

I am wondering if there is a cleaner/lighter solution

Comment: It seems CertainPerformance has given you a good solution, but in the future, the Code Review link I posted in my previous comment seems like exactly the place you'd want to post something like this. It's a great place for when you have working code and just want someone to help improve it, either in terms of performance or cleanliness.

Comment: Thanks @TylerRoper. Honestly didn't even know there was a code review section here :P

Answer (score 1):

No need for a library, you can use `reduce` to iterate over the array of `_id`s, keeping a count of the number of substring matches, so that it resolves to the one with the most matches:

```js
const url = '/economia/finanzas/moodys-coloca-calificaciones-de-riesgo-de-costa/JZF24QAQHBBFPLJQL5VZJPKCZA/story/';
const sites = [{
  '_id': '/la-nacion/economia'
}, {
  '_id': '/la-nacion'
}, {
  '_id': '/la-nacion/economia/finanzas'
}, {
  '_id': '/la-nacion/economia/moodys'
}];


const substrings = new Set(url.split('/'));
const countMatches = str => str.split('/').reduce((a, substr) => a + (substrings.has(substr)), 0);
const { bestMatch } = sites.reduce(({ bestMatch, count=0 }, { _id }) => {
  const thisCount = countMatches(_id);
  return thisCount > count
  ? { count: thisCount, bestMatch: _id }
  : { count, bestMatch };
}, {});
console.log(bestMatch);
```

Comment: I was thinking reduce but got lazy and ended with lodash. Yeah, this looks better to me. Vanilla is nice :)

Comment: I forgot to say thinks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need the item with the max matches, you can use `_.maxBy()` to iterate the array of sites, and extract the item. Use `_.get()` to extract the value of `_id`, because `_.get()` won't throw an error if `sites` is empty:

```js
const url = '/economia/finanzas/moodys-coloca-calificaciones-de-riesgo-de-costa/JZF24QAQHBBFPLJQL5VZJPKCZA/story/'
const sites = [{"_id":"/la-nacion/economia"},{"_id":"/la-nacion"},{"_id":"/la-nacion/economia/finanzas"},{"_id":"/la-nacion/economia/moodys"}]

const getPrimarySection = (url, sites) => {
  const urlArr = url.split('/')

  return _.get(_.maxBy(sites, site => {
    const siteArr = site._id.split('/')
    return _.intersection(siteArr, urlArr).length
  }), '_id')
}

const newPrimarySection = getPrimarySection(url, sites)

console.log(newPrimarySection)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** your `path` prefix is always the same (like it seems it is with `/la-naction` then you could do your own scoring (via `startsWith`) based on the length of the matched string and then `sort-by desc` (biggest score) ... and take the top score:

```js
const url = '/economia/finanzas/moodys-coloca-calificaciones-de-riesgo-de-costa/JZF24QAQHBBFPLJQL5VZJPKCZA/story/'
const sites = [{"_id":"/la-nacion/economia"},{"_id":"/la-nacion"},{"_id":"/la-nacion/economia/finanzas"},{"_id":"/la-nacion/economia/moodys"}]

const getBestMatch = (s, u, p = '/la-nacion') => {  // <-- default prefix
  const topScored = s.map(x =>
    (Object.assign(x, {
      score: ((`${p}${u}`).startsWith(x._id) ? x._id.length : 0)}), x)
    ).sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)[0]   // <-- sort, get the highest score
  return topScored.score > 0 ? topScored._id : undefined
}

console.log(getBestMatch(sites, url))
```

No lodash neeed etc it is just `map` to add the score and then `sort` really.